# Programmatically set the FontStyle to Bold Italic

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I was sure that if I perform the AND operator on:

```
FontStyle fontStyle;
fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold & FontStyle.Italic
```

The resulting FontStyle will be Bold Italic, but to my surprise the resulting FontStyle was: `FontStyle.Regular`.
Please explain the way to programmatically set the FontStyle to Bold Italic.
I use the FontFamily: New Times Roman.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @John: I did provide the complete relevant statement: fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold & FontStyle.Italic;

Comment: Can you format it so that it presents as code. At the moment it just looks like a wall of text.

Comment: Remember this is a bitwise `AND`, which only returns common values (`0 & 0 == 0; 0 & 1 == 0; 1 & 1 == 1`). You want the bitwise `OR` operator (`'|'`) if you want to combine the values (`0 | 0 == 0; 0 | 1 == 1; 1 | 1 == 1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the OR operator to apply both.

```
fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic
```

Comment: can Ypou rpvide a code, or help or anything about the FontStyle.Bold enum?

Comment: @GyörgyGulyás it's documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2